# Как получить значения поля типа enum?

Tags: php, веб-программирование, yii2

В таблице бд есть поле типа enum. Нужно получить все возможные значения этого поля. Есть ли возможность сделать это через методы yii2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static function getEnumItems($tableName, $attributeName) {
    $dbname = null;
    $dsn = Yii::$app->getDb()->dsn;
    if (preg_match('/dbname=([^;]*)/', $dsn, $match)) {
        $dbname = $match[1];
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    $data = Yii::$app->db->createCommand('SELECT column_type AS data FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema=:db AND table_name=:table AND column_name=:column AND data_type = :type')
        ->bindValue(':db', $dbname)
        ->bindValue(':table', $tableName)
        ->bindValue(':column', $attributeName)
        ->bindValue(':type', 'enum')->queryOne();

    preg_match("/^enum\(\'(.*)\'\)$/", $data['data'], $matches);
    $enums = explode("','", $matches[1]);

    return $enums;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'role_user')->radioList(['Пример1' => 'Пример2'], [
            'item' => function ($index, $label, $name, $checked, $value) {
                $check = $checked ? ' checked="checked"' : 'checked';
                return "<label class=\"form__param\"><input type=\"radio\" name=\"$name\" value=\"$value\"$check> <i></i> $label</label>";
            }]) ?>
```

Comment: в бд Тип ENUM,   Длина/Значения '0','1'  и  По умолчанию как определено 0